# Loading content every second without button click

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im trying to create a page where the requested page refreshes after a set interval.

I grabbed some basic code of w3schools which uses a button. However, i want the script to load and display the content without the use of pressing a button and refreshes after a set interval.

I do not want to use Jquery but AJAX instead.

This loads the content onto the page in the div after pressing the button, but would like no button click and refreshes say after 5 seconds.

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","content.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>AJAX</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){loadXMLDoc();},5000);
```

**or**
because you have to call only one method and no arguments you have to pass so use the second one

```
setInterval(loadXMLDoc,5000);//preffered
```

**UPDATE:-**

```
<script>
setInterval(loadXMLDoc,5000);//preffered
</script>
```

Comment: `setInterval(loadXMLDoc, 5000);`

Comment: How do i do all this without the use of a button?

Comment: @user3411002 you have to call this in your script tag

Answer (score -1):

```
setInterval(function(){
    "content you want to refresh"
},5000);
```